# Magento 1 : Show custom attribute on product page and make it popup on click

Tags: frontend, product-page

I am working on magento 1 website and want to show custom attribute ( size chart ) on product page under price and want to make it popup when clicked ( so that size charts can be added in it.

can anyone guide how can i do it.

( i have tried a method i saw on a blog but same didn't worked )

Comment: Are you using any popup js library in your website like fancybox etc.?

Comment: no, am not using any of that